# Why can a user revert accepted edits of their question?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

So I recently I made an edit that got reverted by the original poster: 
[White Box Testing Using Control Flow Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681910/white-box-testing-using-control-flow-graph)

Regardless of why the original poster reverted the edit, I believe my edit made the question a little more clear and evidently the peer reviewer felt the same way.

*NOTE: I had altered code formatting but in this case it was most likely justified*

Anyway:

> **Why should a user be able to revert peer reviewed edits made to their questions?**
>
> **Are there any *examples* demonstrating the importance of the original poster being able to revert peer reviewed edits made to their post?**

My opinion is that, at least in this example:

- my time was wasted,
- the reviewers time was wasted,
- the questioners likely-hood of getting an answer is reduced.

Comment: What's actually unclear about _"Edit approval overridden by post owner or moderator"_?

Comment: Becuase they are the _owner_ of that question and _can_ make any change they want to it, regardless of if it's good or bad.

Comment: @user0042 it's not unclear, more a question of how beneficial is it?

Comment: why is this question getting so many downvotes? to me, it sounds like a valid question to wonder about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OP's have the final word about edits on their posts.

This makes sense, because the OP is the one whose name is below the post.
And, there are quite a few bad edits, including bad suggested edits that get accepted.

People have also been known to vandalize other people's posts, out of spite for (imagined) wrongs.

Originally, a post owner could only roll back edits that they disagreed with. However, a lot of bad edit suggestions got approved.
It is a [relatively recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/168333) that OP's and moderators can override bad edit suggestions reviews, overruling the consensus of the reviewers. In this way, a more clear signal can be given to the editor that an OP or moderator did not agree with their edit.

In this particular case, your edit seemed an improvement. It fixed grammar and improved the formatting. But yes, an OP can roll that back as well.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would still like an example if possible.

Comment: @MelO'Hagan Not exactly an example of this system, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30202859/revisions) was a case of a community-approved edit, that the OP toroughly disagreed with. Revision 6: editor says "Answer is no". Revision 7: OP says the answer is "Yes".

Answer (score 5):

The OP has the final say about their own post as long as no posting rules are violated. The edit was pretty radical so it is hard to say what they didn't like about it. After rejecting the edit they made a (poor) attempt to fix the post themselves.

That being said, what's notable here is:

- The OP has very poor grammar and spelling - such things could be fixed through edits.
- The indention is non-existent. It can be fixed by edits. Or preferably, leave a comment to the OP saying that they should fix it themselves, since posting a wall of unindented code is rather rude.
- The code itself is crap. C++ is a case-sensitive language and this code could never work. Unless they post the actual code and not something sloppily written down while posting, the question is of very poor quality.
- Most importantly, they fail to write a coherent question. I've been trying to salvage what they actually want from reading the original text, but it isn't possible beyond "is this right? explain everything". It is unclear, it is too broad.

> my time was wasted
>   the reviewers time was wasted,

Indeed! Because you should not spend time polishing unsalvagable crap. This post should have been closed, not polished. Flag for should be closed -> unclear instead.

```
the questioners likely-hood of getting an answer is reduced.
```

I would say it had a pretty non-existent chance of getting an answer to begin with. If it is unclear what the OP is actually asking, no amount of editing by others can fix it.