# Edit on answer got rolled back. Did I do something wrong?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

So I was looking at a few old edits of mine and found that one of my edits got rolled back. [Here are the revisions of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51453548/revisions). I also noticed that the creator of the answer voted for [rejection on my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24313201). A few hours later he just rolled back the answer to his original.

Did I made an error on my edit that I have overlooked or did the creator just not want to see his answer changed?

Comment: Nah, your edit was alright. Sadly the post-owner rejected it for reasons unknown. Do not make a big deal out of it. It happens. Good edits are rejected and bad edits are accepted all the time.

Comment: There's no "correct" way of indenting code and even though I personally prefer your indent style, the OP of the post apparently prefer theirs.

Comment: To be fair it looks like the edit wasn't only indentation. There are a few `;` added. Though I'm sure some users up/down vote based on their perceived readability.

Comment: You did not only add indentations. I'm not a javascript expert and don't know if that matters, but you added several `;`.

Comment: None of those semicolons do anything other than look pretty as far as the javascript interpreter is concerned. That's also a matter of personal preference. I didn't notice those.

Comment: @ivarni You are right, but the question to this answer is also from the same person and there he did use the same indent and also semicolons. But I guess he just dont like to see his post changed :)

Comment: The [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code/260246#260246) does state that we shouldn't be making edits to code that change conventions. I'd avoid changes that are style preferences.

Comment: @ivarni depends on the language. In Python indentation is syntax, i.e. there's no preference about it.

Comment: @Adriaan Well, this one was tagged as node so whatever Python does isn't all that relevant. I checked that first.

Comment: @sirzento As you are aware, some people want to take advantage of automatic semicolon insertion, although it [does not always work](https://medium.com/better-programming/you-might-need-those-semicolons-in-your-javascript-after-all-b28154f93ea8). Cautious programmers will use a [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) to catch such problems.

Comment: When spacing does not change the meaning of code, I think changing *clearly unformatted, hard-to-read* spacing into *some* (any) format convention is an unarguable improvement. (I don't think "frequently failing to use intents at all" is a formatting convention that needs to be tolerated due to being a possible opinion-based convention)

Comment: The semicolons are another story. They don't change the meaning of the code (in this case), but some prefer to avoid using them, and adding them goes *against the OP's style*, so adding semicolons when not present originally would not be a good edit suggestion.

Comment: In general my personal rule is to leave code formatting alone unless A) I'm changing something else on the question or answer, and B) the code is formatted so badly (single-line 2000-character SQL queries - I'm lookin' at YOU! :-) that I have to reformat it just to understand what it does.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I think I edit the answere back then because I saw that OP did use semicolons in his question ans also uses indents. But in general, I think indents could be personal (like 2 or 4 spaces or a single tab) but code with indents is for most users a better and better to read code. Could be the reason why I never see a tutorial with code that has no spacing :) (Just like @CertainPerformance wrote it)

Comment: I asked a new question if indents and semicolon are a reason to make an edit or if this is a personal style and shouldn't be changed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401327/should-i-make-an-edit-to-change-only-indents-and-semicolons

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355090/1997232) and also [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270503/1997232).

Comment: FWIW it looks like the original answerer was consistent in the indents at least (not indenting at the first level, but every other level); it's an odd style though, I haven't seen it before. You might want to avoid making edits to code at all, to be honest, I'm surprised it didn't get rejected on sight because "reviewers can't be expected to know Javascript". (Not saying I think it's good that edits are shown to non-experts, maybe SO should have some alt queue for code edits that gets shown to badge holders or something).

Comment: The follow question: *[Should I make an edit to change only indents and semicolons?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401327)*